# Prove that $n(n+1)(n+2)$ where $n\in N$ and $n+1=k^2$ ($k\in N$) is divisible by $60$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

### My Attempt

Let $N=n(n+1)(n+2)$
Now $n=k^2-1 \implies N=(k^2-1)k^2(k^2+1)$
Now if $k=2m \implies N=(4m^2-1)4m^2(4m^2+1)$ which is divisible by $3$ and $4 \implies$ It is divisible by $12$.
Now if $k=2m+1 \implies N=(4m^2+4m)(4m^2+4m+1)(4m^2+4m+2)$ which is divisible by $8$.
This is as far as I got. How do I prove its divisible by $60$? Sorry if the formatting isn't the best.

Comment: Do you know Fermat's little theorem?  If $p$ is prime, then $k^p-k$ is divisible by $p$.  In particular, $k^5-k$ is divisible by $5$ and by $3$

Comment: No I don't, does it have something to do with primes? I vaguely remember something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To conclude you have to show that it is divisible by $5$ so you have to see what the possible remainders of $n+1$ when dividing by $5$ are, and conclude that at least one of $n,n+1$ and $n+2$ is a multiple of $5$.

> If $n+1$ is a square then $n+1\equiv -1,0$ or $1\bmod 5$. It follows at least one among $n,n+1,n+2$ is $0 \bmod 5$ as desired.

Comment: Alright I guess I do this by assuming all integers to be of the form $5n,5n\pm1,5n\pm2$ and on squaring they are of the form $5m,5m\pm1$ right? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Yeah that's a fine way to go about it. My pleasure.